# GNU find and more complex -exec option parameter values

Tags: find, exec, command-substitution, gnu-findutils

This works for me:

```
$> find . -name "*.log" -exec basename '{}' \;
20160114.log
20160115.log
20160116.log
20160117.log
20160118.log
```

1. Is the `{}`, `\` and ';' mandatory when using `-exec` as any other syntax simply doesn't work?
2. The following, more complex example doesn't work:

   ```
   $> find . -name "*.log" -exec echo $(basename '{}') \;
   ./log/20160114.log
   ./log/20160115.log
   ./log/20160116.log
   ./log/20160117.log
   ./log/20160118.log
   ```

   `echo` here is just to demonstrate. I eventually plan to use something like `rm $TARGET_DIR/$(basename '{}')` in its place… It just doesn't work that way (nesting). Any ideas?

Comment: Regarding your first question, yes. The `{}` is replaced by the file name by `find`, the backslash is to escape the semi-colon which have a special meaning in shells, and the semi-colon tells `find` that the command has ended.

Comment: How about using `xargs`, e.g. `find . -name "*.log"  | xargs basename`

Comment: @mnile, that works. I'm wondering here if there's a limitation of what can be put when using `-exec` format

Comment: @msciwoj, sorry, that I got your question wrong :-/

Comment: @msciwoj The issue isn't the nesting, it's the order of operations. `$()` is executed first. And `basename {}` (without `find` to replace the `{}` first), probably just produced `{}`, so it would execute `echo {}` for each file. You can however have it execute in a subshell, by simply doing `find . -name "*.log" -exec bash -c 'echo "$(basename "$1")"' bash {} \;` Or choose some other construct